# Response from Servlet page is shown in new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am using Ajax and jQuery to submit a dynamic form.

It works fine, but the response from Servlet is shown in a new page.

```
function call(formid) {
  alert(formid);
  var form = $(formid); // id of form tag

  form.submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: form.attr('method'),  //post method
      url: form.attr('action'), //ajaxformexample url
      data: form.serialize(), // serialize input data values
      success: function (data) {
        var result=data;
        $('#content').html(result); //showing result
      }
    });

    return false; // not refreshing page
  });
}
```

How I can show response from Servlet in same page?

```
(out.println("<br/>Massage = "+message+"<br/>"););
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing this because you are not stopping what a form submit does:

So, according to [.submit( handler )](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) change your line:

```
form.submit(function () {
```

to:

```
form.submit(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();  // stop form submit and do your ajax call
```

***UPDATE***
According to your comment I suggest you to try the following code:

```js
function submitFrm(obj, e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var form = $(obj).closest('form'); // id of form tag related to the current button

  var formid = form.attr('id');
  alert(formid);

  $.ajax({
    type: form.attr('method'),  //post method
    url: form.attr('action'), //ajaxformexample url
    data: form.serialize(), // serialize input data values
    success: function (data) {
      var result=data;
      $('#content').html(result); //showing result
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<form id="formid">
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitFrm(this, event);">
</form>
```

Comment: hi gaetanoM thanks for your  response , I have change the code accordingly your suggestion but still i have same problem.form data is inserted but it again showing my message to next new page.can you plz suggest me .

Comment: when do you call: function call(formid)?

Comment: on click of submit button .this submit button placed  inside  form .

Comment: I assume function call(formid) is in the html code like: onclick="call(blablabla)".  If this is the truth, you may do: onclick="call(this, event, blablabla)". So, the first row on the call function can be:  event.preventDefault();. Try and let me know

Comment: @someshpurohit Answer updated to clarify how to proceed. If this does not solve your problem, let me know.

Comment: yes i will definitely . i really appreciate with you response and i will let you know .

Comment: @someshpurohit If the answer is OK, you may consider to accept it.

Comment: Yes  gaetano your answer is working it's ok for me. now only the problem is the response from the servlet that is out.print () i need to show on alert()  ; rather than showing "ourform"  please it will solve my problem totaly .

Comment: @someshpurohit One question, one answer. Ask another question! Otherwise, a question will never end.

Comment: Yes its true but if you can sort out this issue i really appreciate with you answer because   the code is provided by you only. please its a request.

Comment: It's should be easy: instead of $('#content').html(result);  you may write alert(result);

Comment: thank you so much your answer is work perfectly for me . my problem is resolved by your answer.